# Check keyboard input

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a typing game (WinForm) and want to check if the keyboard input is equal to the string provided.

Basically, every time a user inputs a keyboard character, it checks.
Below is my code in checking the keyboard character:

```
void TypingGameProper(string rtb_string)
        {
            int mistake_count = 0;
            char[] string_arr = rtb_string.ToCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(rtb_string);

            while (i < string_arr.Length)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(); //I used this but this is just for console app
                if (key.KeyChar == string_arr[i])
                {
                    aStringBuilder.Insert(i, string_arr[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                else if (key.KeyChar == '\b')
                {
                    aStringBuilder.Remove(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
                else
                {
                    aStringBuilder.Insert(i, string_arr[i]);
                    mistake_count++;
                }
                changeRichText(txt_user, aStringBuilder.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I cannot read the key, so I cannot check if it's the same as the current character in the string.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Does the while loop code execute?

Comment: I'm new to c# so I don't know any way to debug it without the key input

Comment: You can't use `Console.ReadKey()` in WinForms applications because you don't have a console window (and also because `Console.Read...` methods all block the UI thread, which you must never do). You need to instead subscribe to various Keyboard events in your `Form` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I read something like that. However, I do not know how to implement it. I saw some code snippets like this: 

'private void txt_user_keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)'
`if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)`
`MessageBox.Show("Space pressed");`

It gives me an error something KeyCode is not part of KeyEventArgs

Comment: Where the user is going to type the value? In a textbox or combobox? Or anywhere in the form? Can you share details of how exactly the user is going to play this game?

Comment: @Chetan in a richtextbox

Comment: Then you need to learn about how to capture the text from richtextbox while user is typing in it... you need to read about KeyUp, KeyDown and KeyPress events of richtextbox.. and try to use them

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Console.ReadKey()` in WinForms applications because you don't have a console window (and also because `Console.Read...` methods all block the UI thread, which you must never do).

Instead, you need to subscribe [to various Keyboard events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.8) in your `Form` - or use Win32 Raw Input APIs (which are painful to use from C#, so I won't cover it). You can do this by either adding an `EventHandler` in your ctor, or by overriding `On{EventName}` (I recommend using `EventHandler` methods instead of overriding the methods).

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.KeyPress += this.OnKeyPressed;
    }

    #region Keyboard input state and management

    // Consider using a ring buffer instead, or at least trim/shrink the StringBuilder once it grows too large (say, after 2KB?).
    private readonly StringBuilder keysPressedSoFar = new StringBuilder();

    private void OnKeyPressed( Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e )
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar?view=netframework-4.8
        // > "Use the KeyChar property to sample keystrokes at run time and to modify keystrokes under special run-time circumstances"
        if( Char.IsLetterOrDigit( e.KeyChar ) )
        {
            _ = this.keysPressedSoFar.Append( e.KeyChar );

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580150/net-stringbuilder-check-if-ends-with-string
            if( this.keysPressedSoFar.EndsWith( "iddqd" ) )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( "degreelessness mode" );
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'm using xaml, should I implement this on the mainwindow of the xaml?

Comment: @NestorDesabille "XAML" is not a platform. Are you actually using WPF, UWP, WinUI, Xamarin, or some other XAML-based platform? And why did you tag your question with `winforms` then?

Comment: I think my question was addressed poorly because I have very little idea about the GUI of c#. But what I'm trying to ask is how do I implement the event handler? Under the namespace of my project `namespace TypingGame`? I do not see anything like `class MyForm : Form` anywhere.

Comment: @NestorDesabille If you don't know how event-handlers work in C# and .NET but you're wanting to handle keyboard input manually in WPF then I think you're trying to run-before-you-can-walk. There's a *lot* of ground you need to cover first and it's not something I can put into a single SO answer post. And besides, WPF, WinForms and other XAML platforms are all **very different** to each other so there is no single, simple answer anyone can give you because you still haven't told us what platform or framework you're using.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what XAML platform I'm using since this project is just handed down to me, but I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: @NestorDesabille I can't help you, sorry. If someone gave you this project then it's their responsibility to ensure you're _onboarded_ successfully, not ours.